# How can I show a mousepointer in an imageItem using J2ME?

Tags: java-me, midp, lcdui

I want to display and control a mouse pointer using J2ME in an imageItem and once clicked, retrieves the current coordinates.However, I have no idea how to do so.Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

[ImageItem has no API](http://download.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/javax/microedition/lcdui/ImageItem.html) to control mouse pointer.

If you want to handle mouse (pointer) events and draw an image, use Canvas or CustomItem objects. Note support for pointer events is optional ie on some devices, you simply won't get these no matter how you try.